# Changing the field CaptionML to ENU in thousands of already created tables in Microsoft Dynamics NAV Development Environment

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013, microsoft-dynamics-nav

We have thousands of tables in Microsoft Dynamics NAV Development Environment and we had not given a value for the CaptionML field. This creates an error when sending the tables to MS Excel in NAV 2013. We were wondering if there is some sort of tool that would allow us to change the CaptionML field value to ENU instead of doing it manually in thousands of documents?

Is there a way to do it within the Microsoft Dynamics NAV Development Environment or by exporting all the tables as .txt files and changing them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may export the translation file either by selecting necessary tables and clicking Tools -> Translate -> Export, or by using PowerShell command Export-NAVApplicationObjectLanguage.

Inside the resulting file, there will be lines with the name of the table, e.g.:

```
T60000-P2818-L30:Test Table
```

You would then be able to generate new lines for the caption, e.g.:

```
T60000-P8629-A1033-L999:Test Table
```

And then import the file using Tools -> Translate -> Import or by PowerShell command Import-NAVApplicationObjectLanguage.

Answer (score 0):

Using Export-NAVApplicationObjectLanguage with -DevelopmentLanguageId flag set to ENU will create a translation text file and will generate missing ENU captions for you. It will not overwrite ML caption if it already exists.

I have successfully used this to copy field names to field captions on tables where custom fields were added with no captions.

EDIT: Flag is only available in NAV 2015 and higher, but there is noting stopping you from downloading and installing NAV 2015 just for this. Resulting translation file should be usable in older versions.